# Where can I find cpu temperature and frequency without any specific command?

Tags: temperature, cpu-frequency

I want to make a shell script that runs as a daemon process and every X minutes read the temperature of every cpu core to report it later with `GNU plot`.
And here is my question, Is there  any file in `/sys` or `/proc` or any other location which this info be uniformly placed across several UNIX systems (not only in Linux)?

If not, tell me at least, where can I find these files in Linux.

Comment: See my answer to the duplicate. I cover all this there on this site!

Comment: @slm The other thread doesn't cover non-Linux systems.

Comment: @Gilles - OK, I missed that one bit at the end. I'll retag this as not Linux then, that threw me off. I believe the answer is there isn't a unified method across all Linuxes any way. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: To answer your other question about "uniformly across several UNIX systems", there is no single place that exists. When I say Unixes I'm talking about Solaris, AIX, Linux, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks at this SOa:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15213255/438544

It mentions these three links:

- http://shallowsky.com/blog/linux/kernel/sysfs-thermal-zone.html
- http://lwn.net/Articles/268958/
- http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/thermal/sysfs-api.txt

They mention that on newer systems you should have all thermal information under:

```
/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zoneN/temp
```

where N is a number starting from 0.

On my Xubuntu 13.04, I have two:

```
thermal_zone0  thermal_zone1
```

Note that my CPU is quad-core, from `cpuid`:

```
Processor name string: AMD Phenom(tm) II N950 Quad-Core Processor
```

so it's not giving me temp *per-core*. It might be that it doesn't even have a temp sensor per-core, but I could not find more information about that. This is, however, the only location where this can be read from that I am aware of.

It is, as also mentioned by this answer on the same SOq above:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2440544/438544

unlikely to be the same across different computers, Linux distributions, kernel versions, etc. - that is, it's unlikely going to be a one-fit-all solution here. You might need to do it in a few different ways or normalize the results if needed.